# Python: get my dowloaded file to my file systems using phantomjs and selenium

Tags: python, file, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm working on web scraping using `selenium` and `phantomJs`, everything is going as I want. But now I'm stuck in a problem which is about clicking on a button that downloads a file and get that file to my system folders.
While searching I found the `wget` library that can do such a thing but I had a problem of the dowload url cause it's not an http link but a javascript link, here is my code :

```
s1 = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source, "html.parser")
                               s2=s1.find('a',
{"id":"ctl0_CONTENU_PAGE_EntrepriseDownloadDce_completeDownload"})
                               f=s2.get('href')
                               #x=self.driver.find_element_by_name("ctl0_CONTENU_PAGE_EntrepriseDownloadDce_completeDownload")

                               wget.download(f,out="C://Users/users MGE/Téléchargements")
```

and this is the error I'm getting:

> raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
>   urllib.error.URLError:

Can anyone help me solve this problem of `wget`, or find another solution to get the downloaded file when clicking on the dowload button?

Comment: Can you put the page URL you want to scrape and point us to the link ?

Comment: Not all webdrivers implement file download - check the if your version of phantomjs does. For drivers that do not implement it you must grab the URL, cookies and other session stuff and retrieve the download using another library like requests.

Comment: okey,thank you for your replay: the link is : marchespublics.gov.ma/…  
if you fill the form and click "valider" the page that'll show is the one hat contains the download link . and the link of download is : javascript:;//ctl0_CONTENU_PAGE_EntrepriseDownloadDce_comple‌​teDownload